# Excel Smart Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Let's say I have the following values

```
Column 1               column 2               column 3
Article - John|Doe     Article - John,Doe     John, Doe
```

I have column 1 in my file. I created column 2 and column 3 manually by hand.

Is there a way to drag the formatting of column 2 and column 3 down to the rest of the rows so that the same idea applies even though Column 1 might have different values? I.e.

> Article - John|Smith

**Edit:**

I actually did this in Excel, but I'm not sure how I did it. All I did was copy and paste some values, but I'm not sure how I can replicate this as it happened by accident.

Comment: As far as I know, the function provided by excel is only data validity, we cannot set the content of the cell to be input in a certain format

Comment: @Binggo_MSFT there are ways types of formatting can be forced upon a cell using a custom number format, but for what the OP wants it would not work.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can use a formula for this, rather than formatting.

Say you have your original value in A1, in B1 you could use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",",")
```

and in C1 use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"Article - ","")
```

I am making some assumptions here, i.e you will always have `article` in the value.